# On iMac, access elasticsearch and neo4j ports on local ip address?

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, port

ifconfig shows

inet 192.168.10.1

I can access

http://localhost/

http://127.0.0.1/

http://192.168.10.1

They are all the same.

I also can access neo4j and elasticsearch ports on the following urls

Elasticsearch

http://127.0.0.1:9200/

http://localhost:9200/

Neo4j

http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/

http://localhost:7474/browser/

But port 9200 and 7474 are not working for 192.168.10.1

http://192.168.10.1:9200

http://192.168.10.1:7474

Something I need to do make the port 7474 (neo4j) and 9200 (elasticsearch) working for 192.168.10.1, but I don't know how.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

**Neo4j**

Set up neo4j on the ip (except localhost), in my case

```
http://192.168.10.1:7474
```

In the neo4j.conf file

uncomment the following line.

```
# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

**Elasticsearch**

Modify elasticsearch.yml

add the following line

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Then start elasticsearch.